# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Tags: php, pdo

he cambiado el archivo conexion.php de mi proyecto de procedimental a PDO y ahora cuando intento acceder a cualquiera de los archivos .php desde el navegador que hacen uso del archivo conexion.php me aparece este error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Este es mi archivo conexion.php

```
<?php 
  
    try{
        $conexion= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=elmercader", "root", "");
      $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      echo 'Conexión exitosa';

        } catch(Exception $e) {

      die('Error: ' . $e->GetMessage());


      }finally{

         $conexion=null;
      }

   
?>
```

En mis archivos .php donde requiero de la conexión llamo con un include

```
<?php 
session_start();
include  "./php/conexion.php";

$traeusuarios = $conexion-> query("select * from usuarios")or die ($conexion->error);

?>
```

Comment: Saludos BetaM gracias por respoder, creo que el problema sigue siendo el mismo, cuando se trabaja orientado a objetos sigo sin entender si hay que declarar en cada archivo .php que haga uso de la conexión la linea que contenga las variables y la creación del objeto de conexión a la bd

Comment: Entonces no entiendo, porque cuando lo hago con mysqli funciona perfecto pero con PDO no

Comment: De hecho si abro conexion.php está funcionando porque entra al try directamente y muestra el mensaje de conexion existosa es decir que está conecntando con la BD

Comment: ¿En `conexion.php` tienes una clase? Si es así, pon tu clase completa en la pregunta, pues **no explicas el contexto donde creas la conexión**, si es en el constructor de una clase por ejemplo o en otra parte. Todo dependerá de eso. Si es un archivo simple, no estoy seguro de que la variable `$conexion` tenga alcance fuera del `try`... no lo he probado, porque tampoco nunca programaría así por varios motivos que ahora no vienen al caso... Además, la propiedad `error` no existe en PDO (es de mysqli), deberás usar `errorInfo()` para PDO.

Comment: Saludos gracias por responder. No estoy trabajandolo con clases. Ok ya cambio a erriorInfo() en el die

Comment: Si el bloque `try ... catch` no está en un ámbito de clase, deberás ponerlo al menos en una función que te devuelva la conexión. No lo he probado, pero no creo que tengas alcance a `$conexion` fuera del `try` ... Ahora hago una prueba rápida y te digo.

Comment: Perfecto gracias, por eso pregunto si de ese modo de programar orientado a objetos utilizando try y catch hay que siempre establecer en cada archivo donde se haga uso de una consulta y se necesite establecer conexion con la base de datos la declaración del objeto de la misma, es decir, que si programo así siempre debería por ejemplo en el archivo buscarusuario.php hacer un try y un catch creando el objeto de conexion y la consulta dentro del try etc,etc.

Comment: No. Tú podrías crear una clase que sirva para manejar la conexión, **solamente en esa clase** tendrías tus credenciales y conectarías allí donde necesites consultar a la base de datos, haciendo algo como `$pdo=new MyPDO();` y luego usarías `$pdo`  sin más. Yo tengo un ejemplo de clase en Github, aunque necesita algunas revisiones, puedes mirarlo para entender más o menos cómo funciona. En cuanto a este código, el problema está en el bloque `finally`, el Manual dice que esos bloques **siempre se ejecutan** y ahí estás anulando la conexión. Si comentas el `$conexion=null` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema en tu código es que estás anulando la conexión en el bloque `finally`.

El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) dice que los bloques `finally` siempre se ejecutan:

> En PHP 5.5 y posterior, se puede utilizar un bloque `finally` después
> o en lugar de los bloques `catch`. El código de dentro del bloque
> `finally` siempre se ejecutará después de los bloques `try` y `catch`,
> independientemente de que se haya lanzado una excepción o no, y antes
> de que la ejecución normal continúe.

Significa que la conexión, aunque sea válida en el `try`, el código pasa por el `finally` y la anula debido a esta línea: `$conexion=null;`.

Realmente, puedes prescindir del `finally` y anular la conexión cuando quieras, poniendo `$conexion=null`, aunque PHP no se comporta como Java o C, y no estás obligado a destruir los objetos, aunque no está mal que lo hagas, para no perder las buenas costumbres y porque algún día el lenguaje puede evolucionar en ese aspecto.

Por otra parte, PDO no tiene una propiedad `error` (como  `mysqli`). Los errores en PDO se manejan mediante el método `errorInfo()`, en sus dos variantes: [para la conexión](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.errorinfo.php) o [para las sentencias](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.errorinfo.php). De todos modos, no es recomendable mostrar mensajes de error interno. Es más, debes tener cuidado con PDO, pues el driver en ciertos contextos, si no lo configuras bien ¡revela incluso la constraseña en los mensajes de error!

Comment: En efecto el finally cierra la conexión, el finally podría usarlo si hiciera la consulta en el mismo archivo dentro del try

Answer (score 1):

Si tu archivo de conexión está en otra ubicación, puede ser que cuando invocas la ruta hace falta un punto para direccionar mejor la ruta.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include  "../php/conexion.php"; // <-Aqui le agregue el punto para direccionar la ruta
    
    $traeusuarios = $conexion-> query("select * from usuarios")or die ($conexion->error);
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Camilo, no la ruta no tiene ningún inconveniente, como está en el post original es como debe ir según la ubicación en directorio

Comment: De todas maneras probaste con el cambio que te sugiero?

Comment: Si aunque estaba seguro que no es el error probe igual y me generó otro error lógico que es que no consigue el archivo porque no se encuentra en el directorio especificado